# Why does Debbie (the little girl) in Billy Elliot vanish behind a passing vehicle?

Tags: billy-elliot

In a scene at the 15 minute mark in *Billy Elliot* where Debbie and Billy are saying goodbye, Debbie vanishes behind a passing vehicle.

I've seen this technique applied in movies where the whole atmosphere is supposed to be surreal or we're supposed to question a character's psyche, but I don't get that sense from this otherwise quite grim and realistic movie.

Any ideas?

**Edit:**  I'm not sure it's related, but for what it's worth -- later in the movie we see a tired Billy imagine his recently deceased mother in the kitchen, then when he and the camera look back she's similarly vanished. That instance is a bit more logical/traditional.

[image]

Comment: It's been so long since I've seen it.  What is Debbie & Billy's status after this scene?  (Does she vanish from his life, either for a time or permanently?)

Comment: This is pretty early on in the movie and nothing much changes after this -- she's in the ballet class he joins and then eventually have a bit of a flirtation. She doesn't vanish and their relationship doesn't really change until later.

Comment: Okay, what? This GIF is 30 MB! Is there any way to replace this with a select few static images or a YouTube link?

Comment: [GIF size] Huh, that's surprising. On the other hand, I think substituting it *completely* might damage the question. Maybe a lower quality\smaller version of this GIF?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Debbie doesn't *really* vanish** - that is, this doesn't seem to be a special effect or an editing trick, and there *is* a realistic explanation to it in the film itself. Though they're hard to spot (especially with captions on), you can *just* make out Debbie's feet moving under the police van. **Debbie simply decided to run alongside it as it passed her**; we just can't see her from *this* particular POV:

[image]

Of course, this choice of perspective and action still seems deliberate. And while we can delve into *Debbie's* role in the film, a simpler explanation would be that it's a *continuation of a theme displayed earlier in this scene*. Remember the first half of this short scene contains one of the more memorable images in the film: Debbie drags her stick across the wall and then across a row of police shields that the wall seamlessly blends into, without even acknowledging them:

[image]

So I think it's just fitting to bookend the scene with a police van then 'swallowing' her whole. ***Police presence (due to the ongoing miners strike) has become such an inseparable part of these children's lives that it's literally part of the scenery - and threatens to engulf them at any given moment.***

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'm still hoping to get an authoritative source from a script or director's commentary or otherwise, but this is a good theory